# How is the underlying keyset of a Hashmap implemented so that add method fails?

Tags: java, hashmap, jvm, keyset

```
public class KeySetImmutable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        hashMap.put("Key1", "String1");
        hashMap.put("Key2", "String2");
        hashMap.put("Key3", "String3");
        hashMap.put("Key4", "String4");
        
        Set<String> keySet = hashMap.keySet();
        
        keySet.add("Key4");
        
        System.out.println(hashMap.keySet());
        System.out.println(keySet);
    }
}
```

In the above code `keySet.add("Key4")` throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. Does it mean this particular instance of Set is a special implementation that prevents addition of keys? How is the underlying implementation achieving this?

Whereas `keySet.remove("Key3");` works fine and removes the element from the `HashMap` as well.

Comment: The views provided by a map  (`entrySet()`, `keySet()`, `values()`) allow removal, but not addition. This is almost always done by extending the `abstract` collection classes from `java.util` which are immutable by default

Comment: keySet() does not support the add or addAll operations. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet--

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keySet()` returns a specific `Set` implementation that overrides `remove()` but inherits `AbstractSet`'s `add()`, which inherits `AbstractCollection`'s `add()`, which throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    if (ks == null) {
        ks = new KeySet();
        keySet = ks;
    }
    return ks;
}

final class KeySet extends AbstractSet<K> {
    ...
    public final boolean remove(Object key) {
        return removeNode(hash(key), key, null, false, true) != null;
    }
    ...
}

public abstract class AbstractSet<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements Set<E> {
   ...
}

public abstract class AbstractCollection<E> implements Collection<E> {
    ...
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @implSpec
     * This implementation always throws an
     * {@code UnsupportedOperationException}.
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException {@inheritDoc}
     * @throws ClassCastException            {@inheritDoc}
     * @throws NullPointerException          {@inheritDoc}
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException      {@inheritDoc}
     * @throws IllegalStateException         {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public boolean add(E e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that these are just implementation details of a specific JDK version.

The important thing is what the Javadoc of `keySet()` states:

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map.The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. **The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations**. **It does not support the add or addAll operations**.